# A false BoolValue is not equal to false

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a script where when the player joins the game, it shows the credits and then fades out, the animation works, but the BoolValue doesn't.

I have a script which creates a Values Folder:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = Players.LocalPlayer

local ValuesF = Instance.new("Folder")
ValuesF.Name = "Values"
ValuesF.Parent = player

local SeenIntro = Instance.new("BoolValue")
SeenIntro.Name = "SeenIntro"
SeenIntro.Parent = ValuesF
SeenIntro.Value = false
```

And another one which does the animation if the BoolValue is false.

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local ValuesF = player:FindFirstChild("Values")
local SeenIntro = ValuesF:FindFirstChild("SeenIntro")

if SeenIntro == false then
    -- The animation code which doesn't use the bool is here
    SeenIntro.Value = true
end
```

I put `print(SeenIntro.Value)` after `local SeenIntro = ValuesF:FindFirstChild("SeenIntro")`
and it prints false, but I put `print("Fade Out")` after `if SeenIntro == false then` and it never printed, the animation also didn't play.

Answer (score 1):

A BoolValue is an object, not the value it's holding.

You need to check the value of BoolValue :

```lua
if SeenIntro.Value == false then
```

Comment: Or `if not SeenIntro.Value then`. (?)

Comment: Hm, for my understatement an Object holds data/functions/methods. True/False are more like special Constants of Datatype Boolean. Or miss i something? - Off course you can make an Object out of the Datatype Boolean in Lua with ```debug.setmetatable(true, {__index = {chk = function(bool) local txt = not bool and "Current State is False" or "Current State is True" return bool, txt end}})``` and it works like a charm: ```print(someunknownboolean:chk())``` - That makes True and False to an Object with Method ```chk()``` - Because Lua is an 'Extensible Extension Language'

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi, yeah pretty much. Technically speaking, a `boolean` is a primitive data type in Lua. Every Instance in the Roblox engine is a `userdata` object. When you compare a BoolValue to a boolean, the comparison will always return false because it is comparing the pointer address of the object to the boolean. That is why you need to access the `Value` property to expose the stored value